# AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, apk

When i try to upload the apk file this message appear :

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the downloaded APK file should not contain a metadata entry called `com.android.vending.derived.apk.id`.

[image]

Comment: can you provide your manifiest file with question

Comment: what is your package name?

Comment: Oke i will add the manifiest file

Comment: my package name is : com.spiller.dictionnaire.arabfrancai

Answer (score 3):

just delete

```
  <meta-data android:name="com.android.vending.derived.apk.id" android:value="1"/>
```

my greetings

Comment: This is a duplicate of the existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apps that are signed by Google will have a 'derived APK ID' written into their `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<meta-data android:name='com.android.vending.derived.apk.id' android:value='[ID]' />.
```

Did you download this apk from playstore console? Build a new signed apk from android studio and try to upload that:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB

Comment: That APK has been signed by   Google Play App Signing. Since an APK is just a Specially formatted ZIP. Extract the AndroidManifest remove com.android.vending.derived.apk.id meta-data tag and put the modified Manifest back in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
When i try to upload the apk file this message appear :
```

The AndroidManifest.xml file in the downloaded APK file should not contain a metadata entry called com.android.vending.derived.apk.id.

```
'manifiest file'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you signed your app with apk-signer you have to turn off the google play signing.

here is how:
https://www.appypie.com/faqs/how-to-disable-app-signing-from-google-play-console

if this didn't work then try to delete this:

```
  <meta-data android:name="com.android.vending.derived.apk.id" android:value="1"/>
```